# Zoom ion icon on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a cancel icon added I want the icon to zoom or enlarge on hover or click. I have added transform but still its not responding.

How can I resolve this?

```
<i class="ion-android-cancel cancel-icon"></i>
```

CSS

```
.cancel-icon:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.5); 
  }
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can only guess. The code given will scale the element correctly, although it will be invisible as the element has no styles or content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working...

```css
ion-icon:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.5); 
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.2.3/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

<ion-icon name="accessibility-outline"></ion-icon>

<ion-icon name="american-football-outline"></ion-icon>

<br>

<ion-icon name="accessibility"></ion-icon>

<ion-icon name="american-football"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: if you are using <i> tag then you need increase font size on hover.. because it's font...

Answer (score 0):

Because its a icon, you can use font-size to resize it. for example:

```
<i class="ion-android-cancel cancel-icon" style="font-size: 0.73em;"></i>
```

You can use relative amounts, to rescale it.